# ERROR:The type org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, apache-camel, spring-camel

Trying to upgrade a project from using Camel v2.21.2 to using Camel v2.22.0

This entails going from Spring v4.x to v5.x and from Spring-boot v1.5.x to Spring-boot v2.0.4.RELEASE.

Project uses groovy-all 2.4.15. We are not using log4j in our project, we are  using slf4j-api(1.7.25) and logback(1.2.3) in our project. Yet, running a Maven install is giving an error saying that some class is using log4j

When I added log4j(1.2.17) dependency it is working fine but we don't want to add it.

Is there something that can be excluded from the spring-boot starter? Any other solutions? Any hints on how to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think log4j or log4j2 should be in the classpath. Spring Boot v2.0.x has log4j2 added. If log4j2 is not compatible with Camel version. Exclude the log4j2 and add log4j dependency and try . Hope it should work..!

```
<!-- Exclude Spring Boot's Default Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- Add Log4j Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```